# Code completion for non .as documents in Flex Builder

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flex3

Is there any way to get ActionScript code completion to work fpr files that don't have the .as filetype? We're using .es for server-side ActionScript and would want Flex to treat them like regular AS-documents. File types can be bound to editors, which brings code highlighting to our .es docs, but code completion still does not work.

Comment: Server-side actionscript isn't AS3, so I don't think Flex would be able to do autocomplete.

Comment: May want to add what editor/ide you are using.

Answer (score 1):

imho, you should look, whether there is an eclipse plugin for the languages you want, since flex builder is eclipse based ...

you may need to download eclipse though, and flex builder as plugin ... as far as i know, you will be able to use a standalone licence with the plugin version ...

if no such plugin exists, you should inform yourself a bit about eclipse ... or rephrase your question and post it with other tags, since this is rather an eclipse related question ...

greetz

back2dos

Answer (score 1):

Start by opening up the Flex Builder / Eclipse preferences, and in the left-hand navigation, select General -> Content Types.

In the "Content Types" list on the right side, scroll down and select Actionscript (might be listed as AS3 -- not sure) from the list, then click the "Add..." button.

In the dialog box that pops up, type in
*.es
and click "OK"

This will associate .es files to be recognized and parsed as Actionscript.

Click OK to close the preferences dialog, and close any .es files you may have open in your editor. When you re-open them, you should have syntax highlighting.